# Alternative to ltrace that works on binaries linked with `-z now`?

Tags: c, linux, ltrace

[`ltrace` doesn't work on binaries linked with the `-z now` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213505/no-output-when-running-ltrace), which is the default on my Ubuntu 19.10 system. It only works on binaries linked with `-z lazy`.

Is there any alternative to `ltrace` that does the same job, but works on `now` binaries also?

Comment: https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace like described here https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace/issues/592. I tried  and it works for me with ELF built with `-z now` on Linux. You can use code from master.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk doesn't really seem to work for me. How should you call it? I tried `./uftrace -a --force ./test` and `./uftrace live -P -- ./test`, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I built it manually but didn't install. I run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/data/uftrace/libmcount /media/data/uftrace/uftrace -a --force ./main`.

Comment: ltrace works for `-z now` binaries on the latest OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. I suspect it's due to [this binutils patch](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/binutils/binutils-revert-plt32-in-branches.diff?expand=1).

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk ah, I was missing that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It seems to work. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [uftrace utility written by Namhyung
Kim](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace).  It's available as a [package
in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/uftrace) although I built
the code from master branch manually to make sure I use the newest
vanilla version.  Example `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  puts("Hello World");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Build with `-z now`:

```
gcc -O2 main.c -z now -o main
```

`ltrace` doesn't work:

```
$ ltrace ./main
Hello World
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

But `uftrace` does:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/uftrace/libmcount ~/uftrace/uftrace -a --force ./main
Hello World
# DURATION     TID     FUNCTION
  58.231 us [ 16283] | puts("Hello World") = 12;
```

See this thread on project's site on Github: [tracing library calls
even if it has no PLT #592](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace/issues/592).